# ACCESS (2010) Insert with nested SELECT (Query input must contain at least one table or query)

Tags: ms-access

I'm not to familiar with SQl or Access.

I'm writing a INSERT INTO query in Access (2010) version of SQL.

I'm getting the following error (*Query input must contain at least one table or query*)

Here is my code

```
    INSERT INTO TABLE ( AsOf, Portfolio, [String A], [Number A] ) VALUES 
    (#DATE#, 
           (SELECT P.Portfolio FROM tb_data_Portfolio P  
                 WHERE IIF  ( EXISTS 
                    (SELECT Portfolio FROM tb_data_Portfolio p2 WHERE p2.Portfolio = 'Some String'), 
                    (P.Portfolio = 'Some String'), 
                    (P.Id = (SELECT px.Portfolio_Id FROM tb_sys_Portfolio_xRef px WHERE px.ext_Portfolio = 'Some String'))
             )
)    
,'String a', 'Number a');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query should start like this (you can't mix values and SELECT in an INSERT)

```
INSERT INTO TABLE ( AsOf, Portfolio, [String A], [Number A] ) 
  SELECT DATE, P.Portfolio FROM tb_data_Portfolio P  
    WHERE ...;
```

I don't understand what you're trying to do in the WHERE clause, but I don't think you can use a subquery inside IIF(). Please explain your objectives and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: In some case the value that I want to return will not be in the tb_data_Portfolio table. If the value is not in the table then i want to look up the value that is in the tb_sys_Portfolio_xRef table.

Comment: Can the value be in both tb_data_Portfolio and tb_sys_Portfolio_xRef ?

Comment: I guess it can be, but I would like the tables to be separate. (Will be easier for the end user) The nested SELECT statement works on its own, but not when its in the INSERT INTO

Comment: I was trying to see if a union would help. Access doesn't like complex queries with INSERT, but perhaps if you save your complex query you could SELECT it in the INSERT statement. I think I'm going to have to give up for the night.

Comment: So the solution that I ended up doing was to query the DB in VBA get the value i needed from the nested SELECT statement, then pass it in the INSERT INTO statement.... I would have much rather had only one statement.

Comment: It's not always better to have one statement if it's difficult to understand. Anyway, I'm glad you solved your problem.